# How put quote with windows Processor(_Total)?

Tags: c++, powershell, slash

When I process with powershell it works

```
(get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |
    select -ExpandProperty countersamples |
    select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue |
    Measure-Object -Average).average
```

Result: 1,75677

but when i translate this request with c++

```
string commande="get-counter -Counter \"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time\" -SampleInterval 300 -MaxSamples 3 | select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average";`
```

Result:

> `The term '_Total' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`

It works when i put only with c++

```
string commande="get-counter"
```

Result:

> `Timestamp                 CounterSamples
>       ---------                 --------------
>   23/08/2019 11:30:33       \\win2008\network interface(realtek rtl8139c+ fast ethernet nic _4)\bytes total/sec :     0`

I try

```
//Processor(_Total)//% Processor or 
\Processor(_Total)\% Processor or 
///Processor(_Total)///% Processor
```

Nothing works Do you know why? thanks

Comment: Your C++ example doesn't have the first, opening parenthesis `(` that your PowerShell example has.

Compare `PS (get-counter -Counter <more stuff>` and `string commande="get-counter -Counter <more stuff>`

Comment: Voting to close because this is a typo question.

Comment: I found the resolution   "get-counter -Counter \"\"\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Free Space\"\""